# error when trying to group records by hour

Tags: laravel

I'm working on a project on laravel and I need to group the records by hour I have searched but with no luck , and until now this is the code that I came up with and it shows an error
here is the code :

```
$buyers = buyer::groupBy(DB::raw('HOUR(created_at)'))->get();
```

and this is the error :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'larates.buyers.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `buyers` group by HOUR(created_at))
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Did you add `->select('the column', 'other column')->groupBy('the column')->get()` ? See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Comment: sadly same issue